# ¿Uso de muchos JFrame? (los que trae por defecto Netbeans)

Tags: java, jframe

No se si habrá una buena practica para esto, ya que tengo una pantalla con un JMenu con muchos items

```
->Menu   
->Usuario  
{  
   ->Iniciar sesion  
   ->Registrarse   
   ->Informacion de usuario  
}  
->Ayuda  
{
   -> Instrucciones de juego  
   -> Acerca del juego  
}
```

Entonces yo creo un JFrame Form para cada uno de estos si es necesairo, ventana de registro, ventana de inisio de sesion, ventana de informacion, ventana de ayuda, etc. Y no sé si esto sea una practica común o haya una manera mas practica de trabajar esto.

Comment: Victor: Algunos considera que preguntar por buenas prácticas es basado en opiniones, por otro lado, a tu pregunta le falta incluir una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema, así que si la pregunta se queda como está, esta podría ser cerrada, pero no te preocupes, de todas formas la podrás mejorar. Referencia:[ask].

Comment: Gracias, lo haré en mis proximas preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la decisión como manejas el tema de ventanas en una aplicación no hay mejores practicas. Si comparas por ejemplo el antiguo Freehand o el Gimp con Photoshop, te das cuenta que algunas aplicaciones usan multiples ventanas principales (que tiene sus ventajas por ejemplo en sistemas con multiples pantallas) y otros manejan esta distribución de ventanas por tabs o docks.

Eso dicho, si existen buenas alternativas a crear multiples `JFrame` que se pueden considerar. La mayoría de estas alternativas estan basados en `JPane` con un layout.

Una mala practica solamente es lo que no funciona o que hace tus usuarios saltar por la ventana (o tirar su equipo por la misma).

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esto, pues lo que tengo funciona perfectamente hasta el momento, sin embargo lo que me da un poco de temor es que mientras mas robusto puede resultar mas dificil de controlar. Será preguntar cuando llegue el momento. Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres te agrego una alternativa? Prefieres tabs, card o dialogo modal?

Comment: He estado leyendo y dicen que debería usarse un solo JFrame y de hijos puro JDialog, aunque nunca los uso :l

Comment: Es una manera de hacerlo, probablemente la más común. Eso no significa que tienes que hacerlo. Podrías por ejemplo crear un `GridBagLayout` y colocar un elemento de dialogo en un `JPanel` con `CardLayout` en una de las celdas. Hay millones de opciones. JDialog es útil si necesitas flujo de trabajo modal, pero tambien hay otras formas de controlar el flujo.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que podría ser una mala práctica si al abrir una nueva ventana la otra se queda abierta ya que sería incomodo para el usuario, lo que podrías hacer este caso sería tener un **JPanel** por cada opción que mencionas y cargar el **JPanel** que se requiera en un único **JFrame**. 
También si lo prefieres puedes usar un **JTabbedPane** (pestañas) en un **JFrame** y así tener todas las opciones en un único JFrame.

Comment: Bueno, lo que tu dices no ocurre, lo tengo bien en ese sentido, se desactiva un JFrame cuando debe dar paso a otro, y si debe regresar al anterior funciona.

Comment: Una mala arquitectura es una arquitectura que no controlas. No hay ningún problema de implementar un distribudor de eventos que cierra los frames si sales de la aplicación, es todo una pegunta que pensamiento inviertes en lo que haces. Abre tu mente y duda hasta a ti mismo cuando dices "creo que...". Si tienes que creer, no sabes. ;)